# JavaScript event not triggering on scroll

Tags: javascript

I hope this is not a duplicate topic as I have checked multiple questions on SO but they did not work for me.

I am trying to make a button visible/invisible based on scroll position so I created a scroll event listener to trigger a function that checks scroll position and does necessary stuff based on that. However, I could not get the listener to fire.

I have checked multiple documentations and tried to make sure that I am doing everything accordingly to no avail. What am I missing here?

[Document: scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event)

```js
const showHideArrow = () => {
    //console.log("func triggered");
    const arrow = document.getElementById("scroll-arrow");
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
        arrow.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        arrow.style.display = "block";
      }
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", showHideArrow);
```

```css
section{
  max-height: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 90vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.scroll-arrow {
  margin: auto auto 5rem auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <section class="intro">
             <a id="scroll-arrow" class="scroll-arrow" target="_self" href="#about">
                <svg width="34" height="34" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path
                        d="M11.0001 3.67157L13.0001 3.67157L13.0001 16.4999L16.2426 13.2574L17.6568 14.6716L12 20.3284L6.34314 14.6716L7.75735 13.2574L11.0001 16.5001L11.0001 3.67157Z"
                        fill="currentColor" />
                </svg>
            </a>
        </section>
        <section id="about" class="about">
            <h2>test</h2>
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you create a working [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do/358993#358993) to reproduce the issue here? that would help addressing your issue.

Comment: I just did but oddly it is working on the snippet. I copied and pasted everything from my code https://jsfiddle.net/0wvg3sxb/2/

Comment: hmmm, ok there seems something missing, where did you put your script? is it in the header? are you sure that your code running after the HTML is initialized and available? make sure that you run the js code on window.load, since its working in snippet but not locally.

Comment: I tried all of these and I made sure to defer the script also, they did not work. I found that the problem was `overflow-x: hidden` line in CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem arises from this line:

```css
html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

I have no idea why and how this is preventing the event listener from firing, but it seems to be working now. I will have to find something else to hide scroll bars

Comment: try leaving the `overflow-x: hidden` only on the `body` element and remove it from the `html` element